# Will IOS increment a push notfication badge number?

Tags: ios, push-notification, badge

I need to write a application which can show badge number on the icon.

I am able to receive the push notification and the badge number is also getting displayed as 5.

But, when the second push notification received while the app is still not yet launched the badge still displays 5.

It is not supposed to be 10?

Comment: no, it supposes to be the _exact_ number you have sent through the push notification; the iOS displays the number in the badge as is but not making any arithmetical calculation.

Comment: you have to accept that Apple is super stupid in this kind of stuff so yea, you have to manage it on the server side, which is by the way the side which has no idea how many badges should be displayed - logical as that :)

Comment: The problem is that you receive push notifications while you are online, but then if you go offline and open your app you have no way to tell the server that it needs to reset the notifications count, and so I guess you will just have to have notification counts out of sync if you use your app offline.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`iOS` doesn't sum the badge numbers you send to the app. It just displays the latest badge number sent from your server. You server should send a push notification with badge number of 10 if that's the badge number you want to display.

Comment: If there is an SMS application and 2 SMS is read and 3 SMS newly arrived will it not display the correct value, how it works there?

Comment: @Dickens SMS is a different mechanism and unrelated to push notifications. The server should know how many unread messages each instance of the app has (the app should notify the server regarding how many messages are read/unread when it is launched. It can reset the badge count to 0 when all the messages are read).

Answer (score 2):

The server who sent the notification has to set the number to 10, not you.
See here for more information: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1

Answer (score 1):

You can control badge number with `aps` dictionary attached to push notification.
There is a `badge` key you can use to set proper count - but counting amount of push notification has to be done on server side - iOS doesn't do that automatically.

[Checkout the APS reference table 9-1 here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH17-SW1)

To reset badge count you should use UIApplication method.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0]
```

Depending on the application logic you need to place that in different locations, but most common usage is to do that on application becoming active.

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the updated badgeNumber from your server. Then updated number will be displayed. iOS doesn't do the summation, It just display the number.

Comment: How can i update server when it is offline whether the message has been seen or not by the user?Later how can i get updated badge count?